# ¿Comparar un String o convertir a int y luego comparar?

Tags: java, android, xml, string, soap

El día de hoy he buscado relacionado; no he conseguido la manera correcta de formular la oración.

La situación:

Trabajando con código, tengo ciertos **Strings** que traen texto (y algunos numeros supuestos para codigos de exito, error, no encontrado etc...) modelando mejor el código, me mandan todo como STRING (aún no quieren mandarme los datos como deberían; los tengo que leer y entonces comparar, haciendo esto me salio la incertidumbre:

```
<GetDEvResult>
<xCodRes_>10</xCodRes_>
<sDscRes_/>
<xCveDev_>1</xCveDev_>
<sDscDev_>NO INTENTO DE ENTREGA</sDscDev_>
```

De la etiqueta <xCodRes_>10</xCodRes_> obtengo el dato de un solo "string" con el substring de java y lo comparo en java con el .equals("10")

Ejemplo:

```
respuesta = texto.substring(texto.indexOf("<xCodRes_>") + 9, texto.indexOf("</xCodRes_>"));

if (respuesta.equals("10"))
System.out.println(texto.substring(texto.indexOf("<sDscDev_>") + 9, texto.indexOf("</sDscDev_>")));
```

---

Haciendo esto, pense en que esto puede consumir memoria y proceso extra.

¿Que proceso sería el mas optimo, usando la clase String y sus metodos, o convertir a numero y compararlo directamente en el **if(...)** ?

NOTA: Recordando que todo parte de una sola cadena.

Comment: No entiendo que parte te preocupa que pueda consumir mucha memoria... el substring, o el if?

Comment: Para el if partiendo del proceso que si o si hay que hacer del substring.

Suponiendo que obtengo el valor partiendo del substring, es mejor guardarlo en String, comparandolo directo del substring o mandandolo directo a un valor entero?

Comment: Estarías comparando 2 strings pequeños, no es un problema. Si siempre tienes que comparar con "10" y luego mostrar lo que está entre otros tags, una expresión regular que matchee ambos tags, y extraer lo que está en el medio con grupos puede ser una mejor opción, ya que todo se analizaría en una sola pasada.

Ahora bien, si los valores a comparar van a ser distintos en distintas circunstancias, entonces quizá sea  mejor usar un parseador de XML, y obtener todos los valores en un solo parseo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma elegante de extraerlo sería:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:.*>)(\\d+)(?:<.*)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("<xCodRes_>10</xCodRes_>");
    while (m.find()) {
      // esto imprime 10
      System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

La expresión regular puedes entenderlo desde este sitio: [demo](https://regex101.com/r/MSOKbU/3)

La explicación es:

**(?:**   es un grupo para ignorar (no capturable)

**.***  captura cualquier cosa

**>**  encuentra el '>'

**(....)**   es lo que estas buscando

**\\d+**  en este caso por lo menos un digito

**(?:<.*)**   encuentra el '<' que cierra y todo lo que lo sigue

El patrón es tal vez simplista.. se puede mejorar.

Comment: Me parecio de lo mejor, gracias AminM!